# Max Utility Function and Finding associated demand curve

Tags: microeconomics, utility, demand

I have a max utility function, therefore;
**U(x,y)= max(2x,y)**
and I am trying to find the demand function x = x(x , y , ), note this function cannot be differentiated. I am familiar that the utility function states that it is best to have x=0 and all of the good y, or vice versa. So I've been trying to solve with the budget line making one x=0 and then again y=0 but I am unsure what to do from this point?

Working so far:
p1x+p2y=M
when y=0
x=m/p1
U= 2m/p1

&
when x=0
y=m/p2
U= m/p2

So now I have two equations in terms of U

Comment: Yeah, I actually do know what it is :) excuse my non-formal language, I'm asking what the demand function for x is for that given utility function... thanks

Comment: I get that, but you wrote "it is best to have x=0 and all of the good y, or vice versa." Surely it is very easy to check which one is better for any given M,p1,p2?

Comment: Hint: Does x=m/p1 or x=0 lead to higher utility?

Comment: I can get the utility of when y=0 and x=0 I'm just getting stuck on showing which has greater utility

Comment: yep, done that, rather so I have two equations in terms of U

Answer (score 1):

From your formula for $x$ when $y=0$, you should be able to find $U$ in terms of $M$ and $p_x$ when $y=0$.  Similarly, $U$ in terms of $M$ and $p_y$ when $x=0$.  The key then is to find the critical price ratio at which, to maximise $U$, the switch needs to occur from $y=0$ to $x=0$.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still struggling with this one, unfortunately, after finding the utility when y=0 and then x=0, U=2m/px and U=m/py respectively. I'm unfamiliar with the term critical price ratio. Thank you for your help so far :)

Comment: If you equate those two formulae for $U$ you obtain a condition under which utility is the same when $y=0$ or when $x=0$.  You can then cancel $M$ and rearrange to obtain what I call the critical price ratio.  One side of this ratio, utility is maximised with $y=0$; the other side, with $x=0$.

Comment: Okay so I have 2py=px and then to establish which one provides high utility? how? Or am I supposed to use that in the demand function? sorry for being so lost

Comment: The demand function for $x$ will need to be in two parts: if $p_x/p_y\geq 2$ then ... and if $p_x/p_y\leq2$ then ...

Comment: To conclude it is safe to say in terms of demand functions that if the price ratio is less than 2 the demand function in terms of x is x=m/px and if price ratio is greater than 2 the demand function is x=0?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.